# empty block is not working with endif inside a loop

Tags: django, python-3.x, for-loop, django-templates

I am builidng a dashboard where empty content has a different view so the user is not viewing a empty area.

It is working well with a **for loop** without an **if block**, for example

```
 {% for dashboard in dashboard_list %} 


    some content

            {% empty %} no data {% endfor %}
```

**Now that**

```
{% for todo in todo_list %}
                            {% if todo.complete %}{% else %} some content



                            {% endif %}  {% empty %} content when its empty  {% endfor %}
```

It's not working and doesn't show the "no data"

Comment: make sure you have `dashboard_list` not none. Also, in if the condition you have todo_list wherein the empty block you have `dashboard_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it won't work... `{% empty %}` is only invoked if there is nothing in `todo_list`, it won't be invoked if each loop pass won't return anything.

To fix that issue, you should iterate through a list that will be already filtered and won't contain any complete items.